# one file Shas and more data

Tags: discussion

Is there one file Shas or more, to search topics and words. I want to make searches, and I am wondering if it's possible without websites that are already organized. Is there a possibility to reach data more directly?

Comment: You can download the full text file of each Masechta individually off of Sefaria. Does that help?

Comment: I can do this with mechon mamre  too. I upload each masechet an search. But two masechtot to gever is not possible

Comment: @Kazi bacsi seems very good. I'm not sure that my technical mastery is good enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the following search phrase in Google, you can limit your results to Mechon Mamre's sites containing Talmud Bavli:

`אמר site:http://mechon-mamre.org/b/l`

Searching in Yerushalmi is quite similar:

`עקיבה site:http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r`